# Suggestions for calendar database

Tags: database, calendar

I found a php calendar class http://style-vs-substance.com/calendar-class-php/clendarclassphp-updates-and-new-version-release/#more-37

When I hover a day gives a link, such as http://127.0.0.1/2009/12/24.

I want to add an event when I click a date.

Now my question is what is the best structure of calendar database.

Should I make a different field for year, month and date?

Please give me your idea please?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Use the datetime type